# Heroku app load failure "not present in the asset pipeline"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep having a fatal error when trying to load my app on heroku. The app works perfectly in localhost but won't deploy on Heroku. The error message reads:

We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

I've checked the logs (see image via link below) The error reads "the asset cow_7 (an image) is not present in the asset pipeline", but it's definitely in the image file of my rails app. Reading the answer to a similar query, I configured the app to serve my static assets and added a gem file: gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production, as per the response. Nada. I'm fairly new at Rails and Heroku and it's driving me nuts. All help greatly appreciated!

https://ibb.co/dew9RG

Comment: Hard to say but I just had a very strange thing happen in Rails 5. Worked fine in dev mode but not production. Turns out my image had a .jpeg extension and changing to .jpg worked.

Answer (score 0):

it's late but in case someone else sees this query. It seems that the problem is that the extension of the image is missing. if it is image.jpeg we have to change the image.jpg

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).